# Google-App-Engine-Like Datastore for Python

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any software library that provides an interface for storing and querying data like the Google App Engine Datastore, but uses a local file or service instead of running on App Engine?

The specific features I am looking for are:

- Stores data as Entities with Named Properties
- Query support
- Atomic transactions
- Python language bindings
- Runs on my local machine

  - either stores to a single file
  - or connects to a local database
    service
- Free and open source

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org). It is an open source document-oriented database system.

Comment: There is even an appengine stub for monogodb . https://github.com/hellerstanislav/appengine-datastore-mongodb-stub

Comment: MongoDB looks like almost everything I want.  I looked at it previously, but didn't realize that what GAE calls an Entity is really just a document. 

I wish I wouldn't need to run it as a separate process, but I can deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out Appscale (http://www.appscale.com).  It lets you run your App Engine apps without modification outside of Google (on your laptop, on your local cluster / behind your firewall, or in Amazon EC2).  AppScale is and does each of the requirements you list here. It automatically installs/configures/manages the datastore service (and all other APIs/services) for your apps to use, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ZODB - not exactly alike but similiar http://www.zodb.org/

from the docs

Some of the features that ZODB brings to you:

- Transparent persistence for Python objects
- Full ACID-compatible
- transaction support (including savepoints) History/undo ability
- Efficient support for binary large objects (BLOBs)
- Pluggable storages
- Scalable architecture